IPC::Run and Applescript
My end-goal is to:

get PNG data from the clipboard on MacOS
do stuff with it (typically with ImageMagick)
put it back onto the clipboard

and I'm trying to do that with IPC::Run in perl
It looks like the minimal example in AppleScript works:
set in_clip to get the clipboard as «class PNGf»
set the clipboard to in_clip as «class PNGf»

generates no error, and leaves the clipboard alone.
When I try to do what I think is the same in perl:
use IPC::Run qw/run/;
use utf8;

$\ = "\n"; $, = "\t";

my ($stdin, $stdout, $stderr);

run ["osascript", "-e", "get the clipboard as «class PNGf»"], \$stdin, \$stdout, \$stderr;
print ("original data:", (substr $stdout, 0, 100) . "..." . (substr $stdout, -200)) ;

run ["osascript", "-e", (sprintf qq(set the clipboard to "%s" as «class PNGf»), ($stdout =~ s/\n//gmrs))], \$stdin, \$stdout, \$stderr;

print ("convert error:", (substr $stderr, 0, 100) . (substr $stderr, -200)) ;

I get errors: the script throws:
convert 64548:64560: execution error: Can’t make "«data PNGf89504E4...26082»" into type «class PNGf»

What's going on here?
I understand this is messy and at a perilous borderline, but why?

You are using UTF-8 characters in your source code. Do you save it as UTF-8? Did you tell Perl you used utf8? Read perlunicode and documents linked from there for more details.

@choroba yes, I did tell perl (fixed the snippet) and yes, it's saved as UTF-8. Read the docs, too. I'm relatively familiar with UTF-8. I'm wondering whether it has to do with how things are passed to IPC::Run

The documentation of IPC::Run doesn't mention encoding or UTF-8, so you probably need to experiment with it yourself. But I'd guess it behaves the same as plain qx or system, i.e. it expects encoded data.

You can also try whether Sys::Binmode helps you.

@choroba - it turns out it's an AppleScript quirk. What's your advice - delete the question? re-title and answer to make it findable for the future? and thanks for the help

Re "and without the decode step I get:" What decode step???

@ikegami - removed. There was one encode/decode step in a previous version, and I left it in by mistake.
It seems though that this is an AppleScript issue in some way that I can't figure, but I could work around.
Better to delete the question or leave it in and answer myself 'cause there could be one poor lost soul trying to do the same?

You might explore Mac::Pasteboard and see if it'll work for your purposes instead of relying on external programs.

There should indeed be an encode step (for the script) since the command parts need to be bytes.  Try this please

Mac::Pasteboard is more oriented toward text. I can't say that it won't work if you get the flavors right, but I can't promise it will, either.

@ikegami - thanks a lot. It works - with some small fixes - in the sense that it returns the same error I get. It looks like it's an applescript problem. Replacing the second command with run ["osascript", "-e", (sprintf qq(set the clipboard to run script "%s"), ($data =~ s/\n$//gmrs))], \$stdin, \$stdout, \$stderr; solves everything. I think that it's the string-to-class conversion that didn't work in AppleScript

Yeah, except that undoes a lot of my fixes/cleanups.

i just noticed I mangled the command, though. Badly. You couldn't possibly have gotten the same output as for your code like you claimed.  /// In what format is the PNG? It's surely encoded using base64 or something, right? Cause args can't have NULs, for starters.

@ikegami - well some of the mangled bits were quite clear, so I fixed it but kept the main logic

Really? Cause I don't know how to fix it, which is why I asked how is the PNG encoded?

@ikegami - here what worked in the end: https://gist.github.com/simonecesano/3c731df400eb1ecee86224b6cc8bc517, including some extra stuff. Feedback welcome
